# Error executing example in RKEA vignette

Tags: r

I am trying out the `RKEA` package, and ran the example listed in the vignette as follows:

```
library("RKEA")
library("tm")
data("crude")
keywords <- list(c("Diamond", "crude oil", "price"),
                 c("OPEC", "oil", "price"),
                 c("Texaco", "oil", "price", "decrease"),
                 c("Marathon Petroleum", "crude", "decrease"),
                 c("Houston Oil", "revenues", "decrease"),
                 c("Kuwait", "OPEC", "quota"))
tmpdir <- tempfile()
dir.create(tmpdir)
model <- file.path(tmpdir, "crudeModel")
createModel(crude[1:6], keywords, model)
```

I got this error message as the result.

```
Error in .jcall(km, "V", "saveModel") : 
  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: weka.core.Attribute.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Lweka/core/FastVector;)V
```

What went wrong? I also had loaded the packages `RKEA`, `RWeka`, and `RWekajars`, if that's of any use for troubleshooting.

**Edit:** My Java is Version 8 Update 66 (build 1.8.0_66-b17) .  `sessionInfo()`output below:

```
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Singapore.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Singapore.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_Singapore.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=English_Singapore.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] tm_0.6-2           NLP_0.1-8          RKEA_0.0-6         RWekajars_3.7.12-1
[5] RWeka_0.4-24      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] parallel_3.2.2 tools_3.2.2    slam_0.1-32    RKEAjars_5.0-1 grid_3.2.2    
[6] rJava_0.9-7
```

Comment: What is your OS? What is your version of Java? I cannot reproduce the error on Ubuntu with Oracle Java 1.8.0_66.

Comment: Do you have both 32 and 64-bits versions of Java installed?

Comment: No, but I have a Java 7 still installed, which I'm hesitant to remove due to another application requiring the older Java.